# Factors from REDCap to R

Tags: r, label, factors, redcap

In REDCap, categorical variables are exported as numbers with labels, and yes/no fields are exported as 0/1 with labels. REDCap offers a R script to transform those variables (actually to create new ones) as factors with labels. The R script is like this:

```
dataset$sex = factor(dataset$sex,levels=c("0","1"))
dataset$indic1 = factor(dataset$indic1,levels=c("0","1"))
dataset$indic2 = factor(dataset$indic2,levels=c("0","1"))

levels(dataset$sex)=c("Female","Male")
levels(dataset$indic1)=c("Unchecked","Checked")
levels(dataset$indic2)=c("Unchecked","Checked")

label(dataset$sex)="Sex"
label(dataset$indic1)="Indication 1"
label(dataset$indic2)="Indication 2"
```

Is there a way to either export those variables directly as characters (I tried "stringsAsFactors = FALSE" in the "read.csv" call but it doesn't work), or to transform multiple variables into factors with the same label? In the example above, how would one transform *indic1* and *indic2* into factors and apply the labels 0 = "Unchecked", 1 = "Checked"?

Comment: Does your instance of redcap allow for API?

Comment: @jpsmith Yes, it does. It might not be the case in the future, so I would rather have a solution to be applied on the CSV export file